# Find the package name and service name of a daemon process in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, daemon

Is there any command to find the package name and the name of the service provided by a daemon process, using the daemon process's name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With daemon running by systemd unit you can find service by:

`systemctl status <PID_of_daemon>`

And for package maybe try to use:

`dpkg -S /some/daemon/binary`

You can use daemon binary which is running, or maybe some configuration file (if its part of package).